# Boosting wireless packet capturing using scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I am doing a project something like airodump-ng using scapy.. It's too slow while capturing packets.. When I run airodump simultaneously my scapy program capture the packet faster.. How to boost the packet capturing in my scapy program without using airodump.. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your platform ?